# OpenGL slick-util missing class: UnicodeFont not included in .jar

Tags: java, opengl, fonts, jar

I have a major problem: the UnicodeFont class is missing from slick-util.jar.

I used eclipse's "search repositories" feature after it said the import could not be resolved, and searched the lwjgl download folder for the class, both to no avail. TrueTypeFont.class is present and functioning normally, but it is deprecated and I would prefer not to use it. Is there any way I can somehow add the UnicodeFont class to the slick-util .jar? If not, is there any other way to get the class to integrate with the rest of the program? Or do I have to render character textures on quads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the slick.jar for UnicodeFont instead of slick-util.jar.